# Update and Use variables from package

Tags: perl

I have following package:

```pl
package My::Content;

our $new = undef;
our $content = '<header>content-start'.$new.'content-end</header>';

1;
```

And the following script:

```pl
use My::Content;
use warnings;
use strict;

$My::Content:new = '++test++';

print $My::Content:content;
```

However the result is 'content-startcontent-end'. As I understand from here, package variable `$content` was set at compilation time and $new value was  taken as undef, regardless of later variable update. Is it possible somehow to set $new value before $content calculation?
As result I want to see 'content-start++test++content-end'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but make `content` a function and it can get recalculated at the point of use.

```
package My::Content;

our $new = undef;
sub content { '<header>content-start'.$new.'content-end</header>' }
```

---

```
use My::Content;
use warnings;
use strict;

$My::Content:new = '++test++';

print My::Content:content;
```